# How to convert String returned by prop.getProperty() into Integer using java

Tags: java, selenium, config

I am trying to read a config file and I want to use that properties value in some algebraic operations. So I need to convert the string returned by `prop.getProperty(String str)` into an integer.

I have tried converting it using:

1.)

```
Integer value = null;  
String string = getProperty(key);  
if (string != null)  
value = new Integer(string);  
return value;
```

2.)

```
String noofdivs = prop.getProperty("NO_OF_INITIAL_DIVS");
Integer noOfInitialDivs = Integer.valueOf(noofdivs);
```

3.)

```
String xyz = prop.getProperty("NO_OF_LINES_IN_A_DIV");
Integer noOfLinesInDiv = Integer.getInteger(xyz);
```

but none of them is working.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: is your property there and is it a number?

Comment: yes it is present in the properties file and is a number. all strings in the file are fetched properly but when converted to integer through any of the methods same exception is being reported

Comment: share the exception details

Comment: Exception Occurred : [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@df503

Comment: @shruti i think harsh meant that u should add the stacktrace of your exception to your question

Answer (score 2):

`int value = Integer.parseInt(string);`

You can then check for a `NumberFormatException` to see if it was properly parsed.

Comment: Then your property is not an Integer, what does it look like?

Comment: These are my properties:BROWSER=CHROME
LOG_FILE_PATH=C:/eclipse/TESTENV
LOG_FILE_NAME_PREFIX=log
LOG_FILE_NAME_SUFFIX=.txt
LOG_PATTERN=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %F -%M():%L - %m%n
LOG_FILE_DATE_PATTERN=ddMMyyyy_HHmmss
NO_OF_LINES_IN_A_DIV=50;
NO_OF_INITIAL_DIVS=3;

Comment: Well there is a `;` at the end of each line, remove it. (Also please next time edit your question to add code.)

Comment: These are my properties:BROWSER=CHROME
LOG_FILE_PATH=C:/eclipse/TESTENV
LOG_FILE_NAME_PREFIX=log
LOG_FILE_NAME_SUFFIX=.txt
LOG_PATTERN=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %F -%M():%L - %m%n
LOG_FILE_DATE_PATTERN=ddMMyyyy_HHmmss
NO_OF_LINES_IN_A_DIV=50;
NO_OF_INITIAL_DIVS=3;

Comment: @shruti, update your original question with all of the code you are using regarding these properties & configuration values and the **entire** error message you get.

Comment: hey @Arran i got the solution it was just a problem of a semicolon. Thanks all and sorry for the silly thing..

Comment: @shruti, no worries - it is not silly but it is just that we can do nothing but flap our hands in the air unless people show us the code that is causing the problem along with any backing information. (i.e, *full error messages*). Glad you got the problem sorted. I would either accept Djon's answer, or answer your own question and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it could be a little bit overengineered here, you could use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) to avoid converting yourself the properties. The framework has also the advantage to throw a [ConversionException](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29) if the property your are reading is not of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Integer value = env.getProperty("name property", Integer.class);